# Set new message count on icon like Android New Message

Tags: android

I want to implement feature such as, when new message is received on Android. Look on the image on detail and please help if you can.

**UPDATE**

I just want to build imageview in xml like new message icon on homescreen, with red circle on the right-top.

[image]

Comment: for this please look in to this [article](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html) android-viewbadger [code](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger)

Answer (score 1):

You are welcome to implement a home screen app widget for that purpose. Or, you are welcome to implement your own home screen, and offer some sort of badging API to third parties.

You have no means of affecting anything else on the home screen.

Comment: @Big.Child: as per above ans. if you create your own Home Screen then Please share it here...

Comment: I just want to build imageview in xml like new message icon on homescreen, with red circle on the right-top.

Comment: @Big.Child: You are welcome to implement a home screen app widget to do that.